# Google Tag Manager being loaded multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have this configuration for Google Analytics wherein I load 2 products in the site's header as such:

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxx-x');
  gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxxxx');
</script>
```

On the same page below the header, the following call is made to track conversions on load:

```
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx'});
</script>
```

This results in gtag being loaded/initiated twice:

[image: GA Calls]
The Google Tag Assistant Chrome plugin has the following complaint: "Multiple installations of Global site tag (gtag.js) detected", and links me to a Google help page that resolves in a 404.

When I remove the conversion event, gtag only loads once, as it should.

Is my implementation wrong/incorrect?

Comment: any updates/news? have same issue... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are not actually submitting 2 pageviews, otherwise it may be a bug in the add-on that does not have any negative effect.

Comment: 2 conversion events are sent despite only calling the conversion event once in the page source. And a pageview request is sent, google complains about a "Non-standard implementation". Removing the conversion event fixes the issue but doesn't send a conversion anymore; only a pageview is sent.

Answer (score 0):

In short: Another google flop on sending you to a 404 or misindicating an issue. It's just how Google implemented gtag.js. We have to live with it. More here: [Google Tag Manager loading duplicate ads scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093554/google-tag-manager-loading-duplicate-ads-scripts/78109999#78109999)